# How to tell if your application is Project or Excel with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I have created a custom class that adds references based on what the macros need to run on the particular Project or Excel file. This class works for both MS Project and Excel. The problem I am having is in the code how can I determine if the application is a Project or Excel file? Currently my code works by default assuming that it is in an Excel file, if an error occurs I handle the error by switching the code from "ActiveWorkbook" to "ActiveProject". Is there any way I can avoid using error handling and just run a check to see what I am in. 
Thanks!

Comment: Try `?application.Name` in the VBE's Immediate Window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jeeped's comment points to a simple answer--test the Name property of the Application object. Not in the Immediate window, of course, but in an If statement: `If Application.Name = "Microsoft Excel" Then...`.